# Tablesorter functionality not working after jquery ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In `document ready()` function i am binding dropdowns and calling dropdowns `chagefunction()` and binding table results.But `tablesorter()` not working after that ajax call.,please let me know how to call `tablesorter()`.

EDIT:

```
$(function () {

  $("#filterByApplicationName").change(function () {
calling ajax post method to load the second dropdown based on first dropdown
 $.post("<%=Url.Action("GetRolesByApp", "Search")%>",{ appId:appid }, function (result) {
//getting result bindign data to dropdown.


}

//calling submit form to get the results of application info
SubmitForm();


}

 function SubmitForm() {

$.post('/Search/ShowResult',
                f.serialize(),
                function (html) {  
--result
});

$("#tblresults").tablesorter(); not working.
}
```

Comment: Can you post piece of code here?

Comment: which grid plugin are you using ?

Comment: please tell me why tablesorter not working getting Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'handler': object is null or undefined  error.please help me trying for 6hours.

Answer (score 1):

Try [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically which don't have `tablesorter()` binded to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the `change` function is not applied for ajax load scripts. so instead of `$(".dropdownclass").change(function(){` use:

```
// attach a delegated event to document
$(document).on("change",".dropdownclass", function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, that is not working because your control is not yet created and you are trying to attach a event, if you use on event it will work fine.

```
$(document).ready(funciton(){
$(document).on('change', '#dropdown', function (evt) {
    alert($(this).val());
});
});
```

Comment: please check my code once tablesorter() functionality not working after jquery ajax call.