# Why tablesorter not working in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code:

```
$(function () {

  $("#filterByApplicationName").change(function () {
calling ajax post method to load the second dropdown based on first dropdown
 $.post("<%=Url.Action("GetRolesByApp", "Search")%>",{ appId:appid }, function (result) {
//getting result bindign data to dropdown.

}

//calling submit form to get the results of application info
SubmitForm();

}

 function SubmitForm() {

$.post('/Search/ShowResult',
                f.serialize(),
                function (html) {  
--result
});

$("#tblresults").tablesorter(); not working.
}
```

Please tell me why tablesorter() not workign after jQuery ajax call.Getting Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'handler': object is null or undefined error.
please tell me I am trying for this from long time .

Comment: you really should tidy your code. I would hate to maintain this after you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tablesorter functionality not working after jquery ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394450/tablesorter-functionality-not-working-after-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: you've also asked the exact same question twice!

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that the Ajax call is getting the data for the table since you do not show that. If that is the case, the tablesorter code needs to go after you add the HTML code to the table, not after the Ajax call.

```
$.post('/Search/ShowResult',
       f.serialize(),
       function (html) {
           //deal with adding the new content
           $("#tblresults").tablesorter(); 
       }
);
```

Comment: JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'handler': object is null or undefined error.